# Collectd not accepting metrics with nginx-ingress tag

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, statsd, amazon-eks, collectd

I am running a pod with two containers: `global-metrics-generator` and `collectd-statsd`. In container `global-metrics-generator` i am running a python script as a cron which is responsible for fetching all pods within the k8s cluster and pushing metrics related to pod cpu and memory to `localhost:28125` which is being listened to by collectd process running inside `collectd-statsd` container. I'm using python statsd client in my script to push these metrics from `global-metrics-generator` to `collectd-statsd` container.

I have been using this setup for close to 1 year now and it has been working seamlessly. But recently i introduced an nginx-ingress pod in my system and somehow even though i see the python script sending cpu/memory metrics for `nginx-ingress` pod to collectd, the metric is not being collected inside `/var/lib/collectd/` folder in `collectd-statsd` container. For any other pod in my k8s cluster it is working as expected.

**Strange thing:**

When i change the pod name of nginx-ingress to any other name to not have the word `ingress` in it e.g.: `nginx-ingres`(note the single `s`), i am seeing that metric being collected inside `/var/lib/collectd/` folder.

The structure of my final metric with custom tags attached looks like:

**What works** - `[container=nginx-ingres,name=nginx-ingres-6bf8b67bb7-ndmjn,replicaset=nginx-ingres-6bf8b67bb7,ip=100.101.28.65,host_ip=10.36.40.229,Namespace=nginx-ingress]container.cpu.usage`

**What doesn't work** - `[container=nginx-ingress,name=nginx-ingress-599c78d7b6-psxns,replicaset=nginx-ingress-599c78d7b6,ip=100.102.33.199,Namespace=nginx-ingress,host_ip=10.36.40.170]container.cpu.usage`

I couldn't find anything online related to this but is the word ingress reserved in collectd/statsd? If so then any idea why am i able to pass `Namespace=nginx-ingress` tag along with a metric?

Comment: Interesting question. Apparently `ingress` might be a reserved word like [here](https://docs.signalfx.com/en/latest/integrations/agent/monitors/collectd-rabbitmq.html) where `ingress` (as a synonym of inbound) is used in metric names. But it's just my guess. If it's not mentioned in the documentation, probably you can only find the answer by analyzing its code. You may also consider creating a new issue on GitHub of this particular project that you're using. But it's an interesting observations that `ingres` works and `ingress` doesn't. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out actually. Interestingly, the issue has nothing to do with the word `ingress`.

We add a lot of custom dimensions to any metric that we emit from our application.
Collectd joins the metric name and key, value pairs(dimensions) passed with the metric together and stores it as files inside `/var/lib/collectd/` directory, e.g. `[container=nginx-ingres,name=nginx-ingres-6bf8b67bb7-ndmjn,replicaset=nginx-ingres-6bf8b67bb7,ip=100.101.28.65,host_ip=10.36.40.229,Namespace=nginx-ingress]container.cpu.usage`.
These files contain the actual values of the emitted metrics. Since all of the dimensions are present in the file name, the length of the file name is generally long.

Linux has a limitation of 255 characters on the length of filenames. Read: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32795/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-filename-and-folder-size-with-ecryptfs. Since we were adding the dimension `container=nginx-ingress` along with some already existing dimensions to all of our metrics we ended up reaching 256 characters. And while debugging the issue before knowing about the limit on file-name length, I suspected `ingress` might be a reserved word hence tried with `ingres` which actually worked, but all it did was reduce the length of filename to 255 characters.

We solved the issue by removing some unnecessary custom tags from all of our metrics.